# Find the height of the stump of a tree, given the angle which the broken-off part makes with the ground

Tags: trigonometry

A portion of a $30$m long tree is broken by 
tornado and the top struck up the ground
making an angle $30^{\circ}$ with ground
level. The height of the point where the tree
is broken is equal to:

$a.)\ \dfrac{30}{\sqrt{3}}m$ $~~~~~~~~~~$           $\color{green}{b.)\ 10m} \\$
$~~~~~~~~~~$ $c.)\ 30\sqrt{3}m$       $~~~~~~~~~~$          $d.)\ 60m$

[image]

My teacher explained that $AB(tree)=30 m$, $BD=x ~~m$

and $DK =(30-x)m$

I didn't understand how come $DK =(30-x)m$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The tree AB has been split at the point D. The top of the tree has fallen to point K making a 30 degree angle with the ground. Since the tree's height was 30 meters, and we are choosing to call the stump $x$, the remainder of the tree along DK must be what is left over: $(30 - x)$.

To solve the problem, we need to know about the 30-60-90 special right triangle. Notice how we can derive it from an equilateral triangle such as $\triangle TRI$. In this triangle, M is the midpoint of TR. Therefore the ratio of the short side to the hypotenuse is 1 : 2 in a 30-60-90 triangle.

Use this information to verify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the tree is $30$ meters. You have defined $x$ to be the length of the part of the tree that is still standing, so $30-x$ is the length of the part of the tree that has fallen.

---

You want to solve for $x$. Using the definition of sine, we have $\sin 30^\circ = \frac{x}{30-x}$. You probably learned that $\sin 30^\circ=1/2$ or that the sides of a "$30,60,90$" degree triangle has sides proportional to "$1,\sqrt{3},2$." You can see this by taking half of an equilateral triangle and using the Pythagorean theorem. Solving $\frac{x}{30-x}=\frac{1}{2}$ gives you the answer.

Comment: Is there a fault in the question ?

Comment: @RK Yes, the fault is that you probably meant to say AB (the tree) = 30 meters. You wrote AD instead.